# Camunda Spring boot Specific eventListeners for specific type

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

My application has two flows for different types like "Task" and "Invoicing".both of them have different flows.
I have two EventListeners (onExecutionEvent and onTaskEvent) . both of these EventListeners do very specific things related to Invoicing. I think I should have another EventListeners specific to "Task". But then, all of these will get called regardless of the type. How can I get only a specific EventListener to get executed for a specific type? I can pass conditions to  EventListeners but should that information be passed when creating the process definition?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking inside your listener if the listener is applicable? You could do this based on process / task definition key and event type.
Example:
https://github.com/rob2universe/camunda-slack/blob/a5c0429cf61d42b0d2574b168ac5b03757420cd0/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/example/events/CamundaEventListener.java#L32

...or you use listeners attached to the specific task definition in your model. You don't have to attach them to the process execution, you can link the to the specific task execution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this will not help me because both of these: Invoices and Tasks have multiple types(variants) of workflows defined.

Comment: then you make the listener depending on the task definition and not on the process definition. Or, as mentioned define the listener on the specific task in the model instead of defining it on process level.
If this answer does not help, then please see if you can rephrase the question, show more of what you are doing / share the model.